# I don't understand this question about BJT in Sedra and Smith

Tags: transistors, bjt

Chapter 6, problem 32.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqBJmM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Design the circuit to establish a curent of 1 mA in the emitter and a voltage of -1 V at the collector. The transistor Veb = 0.64 V at Ie = 0.1 mA and β = 100. **To what value can Rc be increased while the collector current remains unchanged?**

By applying OHM's law I find RE = 4360 ohms and RC = 4040 ohms. But how do I answer the question in bold? I I don't really understand what concept is behind it. Why would the collector current remains unchanged?

Does the collector current vary depending on Rc or is it Vc that varies depending on Rc, keeping Ic constant?

Comment: Do you have access to a simulator. Put a potentiometer in for the Rc and vary it. This would be the best visual aid you could have other than building it. There is a tab right below your schematic called simulate this circuit, click it. Otherwise I'm not for sure how to best answer your question specifically. I'm sure someone will have a better answer. But doing the simulation might help clarify some of your questions for the time being.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try to simulate this on PSPICE and report back.

Answer (score 3):

As `RC` increases, assuming the base current remains the same, and assuming a simple transistor model, the transistor will *attempt* to maintain the same collector current, regardless of the load, `RC` in this case.

If the collector current is held constant, then as `RC` is increased, the voltage across it must increase, by Ohm's law:

$$ v = IR $$

The transistor will increase the voltage across `RC` in order to maintain the collector current by decreasing the collector-emitter voltage \$V_{CE}\$. But, at some point, typically around \$0.2V\$, the transistor can't decrease \$V_{CE}\$ any more, and the transistor is said to be [saturated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Regions_of_operation).

Typically people think of *saturated* as *all the way on*, but it also means *unable to increase collector current any more*.

Comment: Is it wrong to think of *saturated* as `Ve < Vb > Vc`?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick for NPN transistors, that's exactly right; for PNP it's \$V_E > V_B < V_C\$. Another way to state the same thing is: a transistor is saturated when both junctions are forward biased.

Answer (score 0):

This is the "common base" configuration amplifier.  As long as the collector is negative relative to the base, nearly all the emitter current flows to the collector.  A fraction of the emitter current is recombined in the base region and flows out the base. (Look at the "alpha" characteristic of the BJT.)  When the collector is no longer negative relative to the base (for NPN BJT), the electrical field from the collector can not pull any more charge carriers through the base region into the collector. Any charge beyond what is needed to neutralize the field from collector to base flows from emitter to base terminal.
Input impedance of this configuration is low, output impedance is high, and there is an intrinsic negative feedback which makes this configuration nearly linear in the unsaturated transfer range of operation.  There is also an intrinsic shielding of the input from the output by the base region which helps this configuration work well at higher frequencies.